# Unable to import ssl on linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ssl, shared-libraries

When I try to import `ssl` on any Python version I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: symbol X509_chain_up_ref, version
OPENSSL_1.0.2 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference
```

I have compiled Python 3.5 myself with `libssl-dev` version `1.0.2`. According to aptitude I have `libssl1.0.0.0` version `1.0.2` and `openssl` version `1.0.2`  installed.

It seems to be a problem with the different version of `libssl`, `openssl` and `libssl-dev` but I have installed an reinstalled the newest version of all of them via the Package manager.

Im using Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit