# problems with dynamically linked libraries

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

**Problem:**
When I try to open some applications I get errors from the linker like this:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler-qt5.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZN6QDebugD1Ev
```

Some applications affected are

- texstudio shows
  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler-qt5.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZN6QDebugD1Ev`
- IPython's `qtconsole` shows
  `/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK12QStorageInfo11displayNameEv`
- konsole (KDE's terminal emulator - I'm using Unity though) shows 
  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5ItemViews.so.5: undefined symbol: ...`
- granatier (a KDE game), KSysguard and KAddressbook also show errors in `KF5` libraries
- VLC seems to be affected too since it says there is something wrong with Qt 4 (see below). However it doesn't ecplicitely say it's a linking problem.

It seems to be a problem with dynamic linking and I my guess would be that the problem is in the libraries

**Qt**
all of this errors seem to come from Qt linked libraries ("Qt" appears in most filenames and most symbol names). AFAIK KDE ist baed on Qt, which would explain why all KDE applications fail.
It seems to affect both Qt 4 and 5

I also had a [similar problem with ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518638/unable-to-import-ssl-on-linux) but it went away eventually (maybe an update).

I'm using `ld` 2.25

**Why I'm asking here**
I realize that my Question is not about programming. The [help center](http://Questions%20about%20general%20computing%20hardware%20and%20software%20are%20off-topic%20for%20Stack%20Overflow%20unless%20they%20directly%20involve%20tools%20used%20primarily%20for%20programming.) states that

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.

This seems to be a problem with the linker / the dynamic libraries so I would say it kind of involves programming tools.
If you disagree please spare the downvotes and write a comment explaining you POV.

Comment: did you recompile or installed different version of Qt library?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk I've tried reinstalling different Qt packages (those containing the problematic libraries)

Comment: so, either Qt lib or the software using it is not from the official distro's repository?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk that would be an explanation, but I installed both from the package manager and both have the correct versions

Comment: are you using stable branch of your OS?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk yes but the problems started happening when I accidentally switsched to unstable. See more [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/716506/lots-of-symbol-lookup-errors-in-dynamically-linked-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this kind of problems happen a lot if you switch to 'unstable'.

What you need to do is downgrade all of your packages back to 'stable'. Modifying sources.list wouldn't be enough, you also need to change priorities.

Look this thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117122/how-to-get-back-from-testing-to-stable-kernel-downgrade

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems the source of the problem was that I had Qt linked libraries like `libQt5Core.so.5` in `/usr/local/lib`. When I remove them everything worked again.
I've read that the package manager doesn't put any libraries there, so it was probably me who did a dumb mistake. It looks like it wasn't a programming problem at all in the end.